# Using return value from a function executed on a different thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I realize this code needn't be multithreaded but there was a concern earlier in development that made it necessary to move it to a worker thread.

Since I'm returning `Action` values to the calling method, I'd like to use that return value to update the UI correspondent to the change that was executed as a result of the user's keypress.

I know I can't just declare the UserWorkItem as a value into a `Action` value, so how should I go about doing this?

Here's the code:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => ProcessUserInput(e.KeyCode));

    // I want to use the return value from ProcessUserInput
    // to update the UI according to the change that took place.
}

// Update object values based on specified inputs
private Action ProcessUserInput(Keys keyCode)
{

    switch (keyCode)
    {
        // beacon
        case Keys.B:
            if (Beacon.Status == BeaconStatus.Working)
            {
                Beacon.Status = BeaconStatus.NotWorking;
                return Action.DisableBeacon;
            }
            else
            {
                Beacon.Status = BeaconStatus.Working;
                return Action.EnableBeacon;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're looking for `await Task.Run()`.

Comment: Someone else told me the same but I don't know how to implement it. An example would be more helpful

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443(vs.110).aspx